# Bluetooth icon disappeared a while ago, then it just won't turn on under any circumstances

Tags: bluetooth, rfkill

The bluetooth icon on the top bar just disappeared nearly a month ago. I tried turning it on through systems settings. But the bluetooth just keeps saying disabled (even though the switch slide bar says ON). I have already tried rfkill unblocking all bluetooth options but no luck. Could anyone please help? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What Ubuntu version? You may want to edit it into your question

Comment: Is there a hardware switch you accidentally hit? Is it turned off in BIOS? What version of Ubuntu? What Bluetooth/WiFi chip is it? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please open a terminal and issue the following command `lsb_release -a` and [edit] the output into your post. thank you for helping us help you!